What determines the fee payer on a token swap?
On a CEX both parties will, depending on their respective volumes of trading, typically pay a fee to buy and sell a pair. One will be the maker the other the taker and fees will change accordingly.
When swapping tokens via Phantom wallet for this test account I see that I am the fee payer and the counter party pays nothing:


However when selling I am also the fee payer and again the counter party pays nothing - in fact their SOL balance doesn't even change (which is another question - where is their corresponding SOL credit for my accounts debit?)


What determines who pays? It seems I pay whether I'm buying or selling? Is there another related tx somewhere that I am not seeing? I thought the txs were supposed to be atomic so both the DR and CR's should all add up under a single tx but SOL just seems to disappear, in that it doesn't show up as a CR in the counter party's wallet (if I'm selling) or as DR if I'm buying.
I've also confirmed this with other explorers and querying an RPC directly - a part of the tx always seem to be missing a balance adjustment.

If you are sending the transaction through Phantom's ui, it likely automatically sets your address as the transaction fee payer since you are the one sending the transaction.
By default, the first signer on the transaction is the transaction fee payer.

I understand what you mean re: first signer though the tx goes through radium which is an AMM so if I'm the buyer, the seller must also be initiating a tx at their end too in order to sell. It also happens if I buy/sell through either Jupiter or Radium directly. It seems I always pay the tx fee. It's not the amt the bugs me, its tiny, it's not knowing precisely how it works.

The other party will be paying fees when they send their transaction, whether that's creating a sell order on an order book or LPing on an AMM. The protocol is matching you, but it doesn't work like how you're thinking. The seller isn't submitting a matching transaction at the exact same time and freeloading on your fee.
